# Transitive inference with OWL-RL on RDFLIB

Tags: python, rdf, owl, rdflib, reasoner

I am trying to use an OWL reasoner on an RDF graph which I have created using `rdflib` as follows:

```
ex = Namespace('http://example.org#')

g = Graph()
g.bind("ex", ex)

g.add((ex.Bob, ex.drives, ex.Car))
g.add((ex.Car, RDF.type, ex.Truck))
g.add((ex.Truck, RDFS.subClassOf, ex.Vehicle))
```

(A car is not really a type of truck, but I am just trying out the reasoner).

After running the reasoner, my aim is to be able to infer that if Bob drives a car, and a car is a type of truck, and a truck is a subclass of vehicle, then Bob drives a vehicle.

When I ask if a car is a type of vehicle, the result is `True`:

```
b = g.query("""
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org#>
ASK {
    ex:Car rdf:type ex:Vehicle .
} 
""")
print('Car is a type of Vehicle:', bool(b)) # prints True
```

But when I ask if Bob drives a vehicle, I get a `False`:

```
b = g.query("""
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org#>
ASK {
    ex:Bob ex:drives ex:Vehicle .
} 
""")
print('Bob drives a vehicle:', bool(b)) # prints False
```

I realize from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182210/python-rdflib-transitive-query) that I can write some code to add the kind of triples I want ***after*** reasoning is done. But if the behavior I want is already supported by OWL/RDF semantics, I would prefer to correct my approach and let the reasoning semantics do its work. I feel like I may be missing a fundamental principle in how the inference is supposed to work, but I am a novice in this area and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

(I used [`owlrl`](https://owl-rl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for reasoning by running `DeductiveClosure(OWLRL_Semantics).expand(g)`).

Comment: I do not understand. What is not working? You have a graph, then you expand the graph, then you run the query on the expanded graph. Done

Comment: Oh I am already doing that. My question is, after expanding the graph, I want to be able to infer that Bob drives a vehicle. When I run that query (does Bob drive a vehicle?) on the expanded graph, it returns False.

Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity - I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: You could also ask `ex:Bob ex:drives ex:Truck`. You will get `False` as well. `ex:Car` is an individual, `ex:Truck` and `ex:Vehicle` are classes.